# Returning Variable Page Route Value to Page (URL Rewriting)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

In my global.asax.vb I have a rule like so:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("defaultRoute", "{*value}", "~/default.aspx")
```

So, if someone enters:

> http://www.mydomain.com/janedoe

Even though that page doesn't exist, the application pulls up default.aspx

Now, if this wasn't using a wildcard it would be easy to pull this value in on default.aspx like so:

```
Dim prospect as String = Page.RouteData.Values("value")
```

But this doesn't seem to work with wildcards, e.g.:

```
Dim prospect as String = Page.RouteData.Values("*value")
```

How can I get the page to pick up these variable values? e.g. one time might be janedoe, another johndoe, another goose, another 12345, etc. Whatever it is, I want it to be returned into the string prospect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question ended up being exceedingly simple...so much so I feel a little dumb (except for the fact that no one else answered the question :)):

In my case all I needed to do was change my code to the following:

```
Dim prospect as String = Page.RouteData.Values("value")
```

In other words, I removed the wildcard character from the value name.